# Simple inline of require

Tags: javascript

I have a small nodejs program like the following

```js
const angles = require('angles');
console.log(angles.difference(angles.degree(90), angles.degree(30));
```

And another small library file, `angles.js`

```js
function difference(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}
function degree(d) {
  return d;
}
module.exports = {difference: difference, degree: degree};
```

How can I inline the second source file into a single combined one for example something like this.

```js
const angles = function(module) {
  function difference(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  }
  function degree(d) {
    return d;
  }
  module.exports = {difference: difference, degree: degree};
}({}).exports;
console.log(angles.difference(angles.degree(90), angles.degree(30));
```

I tried browserify, but it added lots of preamble with uglified/minified code. What if I just want something simple like this? How can it be done? I understand there are many corner cases you can create where this is not possible, but let's assume the program and also library file(s) are always this nicely arranged, how to do it? Is there suitable library?

Comment: Why not just keep them separate and use modules the way you're doing? Concatenating Node code down to one file isn't really a common practice, since it's presumably running on a server or on the command line, so there's no overhead delivering it over a network. You can do it with Gulp (or just plain `cat`), but could run into issues with conflicting identifiers.

Comment: It's for a pascal -> js compiler, so that's why it would be need to just have something like this. I'll probably just write something my self as plan B. Check it out here: https://vidstige.github.io/pascaljs/

Comment: Ooh very interesting. I'll update with a real answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rollup would be a good bundler for this. [This template](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-starter-lib) works fine, but may do more than you need. This barebones rollup config doesn't do much in the way of mangling:

```
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';

export default [
    {
        input: 'src/index.js',
        output: [
            { file: './output.js', format: 'cjs' },
        ],
        plugins: [
            resolve(),
            commonjs()
        ]
    }
];
```

If you install `rollup` and those two plugins, and add that to your project, you can run with `rollup -c` and it will produce one bundle. The two plugins are to get CJS modules to work, because Rollup wants to use ESM.

This is the output of your code with that rollup config:

```
'use strict';

function difference(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}
function degree(d) {
  return d;
}
var angles = {difference: difference, degree: degree};

console.log(angles.difference(angles.degree(90), angles.degree(30)));
```